# take() with debounceTime() takes the last element only

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am new to RxJS and have a doubt.

Below code works fine and prints 'Robert" and 'Mark'

```
    let studentNames = ['Robert','Mark','Sam'];
    from(studentNames).pipe(take(2)).subscribe(
      data => 
      {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

But when I added debounceTime it only prints 'Mark'. Why is this?

```
    let studentNames = ['Robert','Mark','Sam'];
    from(studentNames).pipe(take(2),debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(
      data => 
      {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Docs of [`debounceTime`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime):

> Emits a notification from the source Observable only after a particular time span has passed without another source emission.

In your case, your source emits two values without any time in-between.  `debounceTime` will then wait `1000ms` after the last emission is received and emit it.

The order of your operators within the `pipe` matters.  Notice that if you put `debounceTime` before `take` you will see different behavior; only "Sam" would be emitted.  This is because `debounceTime` would receive all three emissions, then only emit the final one after the `1000ms` has passed.  The `take(2)` wouldn't even come into play because the source (`from`) would complete before the `take` received two emissions.